# looking for twit and text message style stopwords

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, stop-words

I have used R for mining the tweets and I got the most frequent words used in the tweets. However the most frequent words are like this:

```
 [1] "cant"     "dont"     "girl"     "gonna"    "lol"      "love"    
 [7] "que"      "thats"    "watching" "wish"     "youre"
```

I am looking for trends and names and events in the texts.
I am wondering if there is a way to remove this text message style words (such as gonna,wanna, ...) from the corpus? Is there any stopwords for them? 
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look into http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/TweetNLP/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text mining package maintains it's own list of stopwords and provides useful tools for managing and summarizing this type of text.

Let's say your tweets are stored in a vector.

```
library(tm)
words <- vector_of_strings
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(words))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, function(x) tolower(x))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, 
                stopwords()))
```

You can use the last line with your own list of stopwords():

```
stoppers <- c(stopwords(), "gonna", "wanna", "lol", ... )
```

Unfortunately, you'll have to generate your own list of "text messaging" or "internet messaging" stopwords.

But, you could cheat a bit, by borrowing from NetLingo ( http://vps.netlingo.com/acronyms.php )

```
library(XML)
theurl <- "http://vps.netlingo.com/acronyms.php"
h <- htmlParse(theurl)
h <- getNodeSet(h,"//ul/li/span//a")
stoppers <- sapply(h,xmlValue)
```